# Show that: $\frac{D_n}{\langle a\rangle}\simeq\mathbb{Z_2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Show that: $$\frac{D_n}{\langle a\rangle}\simeq\mathbb{Z_2}$$
where $D_n$ is dihedral group and $a$ is generator of order $n$.

Comment: I changed $<a>$ to $\langle a\rangle$.  That is standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D_n$ be the dihedral group of the regular $n$-sided polygon, and let $\langle a \rangle$ be the cyclic subgroup of $D_n$ generated by the rotation $a$.  Then, the subgroup $\langle a \rangle$ has index 2 in $D_n$, and hence is a normal subgroup of $D_n$.  The quotient group $D_n / \langle a \rangle$ has order 2.  This group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ because there is only one group of order 2 (up to isomorphism), i.e. $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Answer (score 2):

The quotient group is the group of cosets.  When there are only two cosets, the quotient group is a group with only two elements.  There is (up to isomorphism) only one group with only two elements.

Comment: I'm trying to use the isomorphism theorem, however I am unable to set the application between these groups.

Comment: There are several "isomorphism theorems".  One of them says that the quotient group of a group by the kernel of a homomorphism is isomorphic to the image of the homomorphism.  In this case the homomorphism would have to map each rotation (including $a$) to $0$ and each reflection to $1$.  If you know that in $\mathbb Z_2$ you have $0+0=0$ and $0+1=1+0=1$ and $1+1=0$, then in order to show that the mapping described here is a homomorphism, you just need to show that the composition of two rotations is a rotation, the composition of a rotation and a reflection is a reflection, and the....

Comment: ....composition of two reflections is a rotation.

Answer (score 1):

Let $D_n=\langle a,b:a^n=1, b^2=1, b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}\rangle$ and write multiplicatively $\mathbb{Z}_2\cong C_2=\{1,x\}$.

Define a map $\phi:  D_n \rightarrow C_2$ by
$$\phi(a)=1$$
$$\phi(b)=x.$$

You can check that $\phi$ yields a surjective homomorphism and $\ker(\phi)=\langle a \rangle$.

Comment: I do not understand who is the element $x$

Comment: Just an element of order 2.